# AngularJS $http won't fire second .then function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have this piece of code where the response status code is 403. The problem is it will never fire the second function, it simply does nothing.

**I've seen similar errors but people were using interceptors, which I'm not**.

```
 Itens.signUp($scope.user, confirmation).then(function (response) {
   console.log('success');
}, 
 function (response) {
   console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error in there. Please fix that and show us your actual code.

Comment: "*people were using interpreters, which I'm not.*" - what does that mean? What are you using then?

Comment: Fixed that. Interceptor*

Comment: OK. Please show us the implementation of your `signUp` function, otherwise there's no way to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @Bergi I'm ashamed to say that but it was only a syntax error. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below isn't formatted right.

```
.then(function(response) {
    console.log('success');
  }),
  function(response) {
    console.log('error');
  };
}
```

It should be like this:

```
.then(function(response) {
  console.log('success');
}, function(response) {
  console.log('error');
});
```

Alternatively you could also do this:

```
.then(function () {
  console.log('success');
})
.catch(function () {
  console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: Notice there's a [difference between `.then(…).catch(…)` and `.then(…, …)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572).

Comment: I'm ashamed for that, but it took me almost a day to realize a syntax error. Thanks mate.